# Is there an explicit formula for a integral recurrence relation (concerning polynomials)?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Is there some general explicit solution to the equation $p_n(x)= k\int_{0}^{x}  p_{n-1}(x) dx +b$, where $p(0)=a$, and $k$, $b, a$ are just constants. I need this for a more specific example, but I thought maybe there was a more general formula, though I haven't found anything after searching for a while. Is there a way to express the polynomial $p_n(x)$ explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

After computing the first few such polynomials, I found that the pattern was

$$p_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}a(xk)^n+b\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m!}(xk)^m$$

It is easy to show that this is the general form by induction. The statement is obviously true for $n=0$. Then

$$k\int_0^xp_n(t)dt+b=k\int_0^x\left(\frac{1}{n!}a(xk)^n+b\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m!}(xk)^m\right)dx +b$$

$$=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}a(xk)^{n+1}+b\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(m+1)!}(xk)^{m+1}+b$$

$$=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}a(xk)^{n+1}+b\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m!}(xk)^{m}+b$$

$$=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}a(xk)^{n+1}+b\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{m!}(xk)^{m}=p_{n+1}(x)$$

Interestingly, as $n$ approaches infinity these polynomials approach the function $b e^{kx}$. This should come as no surprise as

$$k\int_0^x be^{kt}dt+b=kb\left(\frac{1}{k}(e^{kx}-e^0)\right)+b=be^{kx}+b-b=be^{kx}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I cite you for my school paper, since this is a big part of the overall problem?

Comment: Sure, have at it. Another interesting point is that the initial starting polynomial doesn't matter. That is, regardless of $p_0(x)$ (it could also be a non-constant polynomial) you will always get the same limiting behavior

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a bit much too ask, but what happens when $ p_n(x)= k\int_{0}^{x}  p_{n-1}(x-z) dx +b, p_0(x)=a, and for x<z, p_n(x-z)=0 $, or in other words for $x<0, p_n(x)=0 $ I tried my best at this with the same approach, and it kinda worked out, except $p_1(x)$ for me stays the same in both cases, which doesn't make sense in the context of the problem, so I'm pretty sure I made a mistake, I just don't know where

Comment: This changes things as $p_n(x)$ is no longer a polynomial. I would suggest writing a new question with all the details (linking to this question) as it probably is to much to answer in these comments.