# Is there an explicit formula for a integral recurrence relation (polynomials)?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Is there some general explicit solution to the equation $p_n(x)= k\int_{0}^{x}  p_{n-1}(x-z) dx +b$, where $_0(x)=a$, and k, b, a and z are just constants. For x< z, $p_n(x)$ is "replaced" by a different overall equation, so that case doesn't really matter. Is there a way to express the polynomial $p_n(x)$ explicitly? I already asked a similar question ([Is there an explicit formula for a integral recurrence relation (concerning polynomials)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698865/is-there-an-explicit-formula-for-a-integral-recurrence-relation-concerning-poly)) for which I got an answer, but it was a bit simpler question.